# Adding navigation drawer to existing application which has around 40 activities

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I have one question. My application  has around 40 activities. Now my requirement to add Navigation Drawer to my app after login activity. **The question is that do I need to convert all my activities to fragments or can I just add Navigation drawer to my existing activities?**
Appreciate your support.

Comment: add your activities to your navigation graph(if you are using android jitpack) then navigate to the activities easily....
if you are not using android jitpack...i dont think you need to navigate to all your 40 pages from drawer so you can change the pages that you need to navigate from navigation drawer to fragment other leave as it is.

Comment: @unownsp that is not what the OP is asking. "I don't think" -> what you "think" is irrelevant (no disrespect) but you don't know the use-case of the OP, nor you are his PO dictating what must be done and how. The question is valid, since the navigation drawer works by _wrapping_ the content in another widget, the OP's question is "do I have to modify all my 40 activities, make them fragments so they sit inside the DrawerLayout?"

Comment: @MartinMarconcini yes you put my question accurately but on the other hand unownsp has made a valid point that I'll not be navigating all my 40 pages from navigation drawer only 4-6.

Comment: @lmtiyaz yes so if you are navigating 4 to 6 pages from your navigation drawer you can change that 4 to 6 pages to fragment and no need to do to others